# $\int x^x\,dx$ - What is it, and why?

Tags: calculus, integration

As a high school calculus student, I stumbled across the possibilities for:
$$\int x^x\,dx$$ 
My friends and I are currently stumped. My first idea was:
$$ \left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) x^{x+1} $$
But I doubt it is this simple. I've read through multiple forums, and cannot find any solution or explanation! Please help shed some light on this mysterious intregral.

Comment: You might want to see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream

Comment: Though I have not seen any proof yet, I am pretty sure this integral does not admit an elementary expression.

Comment: @VanillaCreme What do mean by a definitive solution? There is no antiderivative that exists from $[0,\infty]$. There is however a taylor series that has an integral to be taken?

Comment: $x^x$ is $e^{x ln x}$ (more or less by definition). You can then use the power series for $e^x$ to get some power series expression for the antiderivative.

Comment: This [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative) may help.

Comment: Regarding your idea: The power rule only works for constant powers, not variable ones.

Comment: I looked into this a lot about 15 years ago, and it turned out that the function $f(x)=x^x$ has no primitive expressible in terms of elementary functions. In other words, the integral admits no solution expressible in terms of the usual elementary functions.

Comment: What about if we differentiated $f(x)=x^x$ $n$ times and tried to observe the general formula for the $n$th derivative of $f$ and use $n=-1$ to attempt at the antiderivative?

Comment: @SimpleArt, That just does not work even for $f(x) = 1/x$, where derivatives of arbitrary order are nice rational functions $f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^n n! x^{-n-1}$ but $\int f(x) \, dx$ is not. For other classical examples such as error functions and elliptic integrals, a branch of area called [differential Galois theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) plays role in to prove that they are not expressible in terms of elementary functions. The link in Raymond's comment shows how it is used to prove that $\int x^x \, dx$ does not elementary expressions.

Comment: This is not too related, but you might be interested in the kind of questions asked by the folks at the [Tetration Forum](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/index.php)

Comment: @SangchulLee Yeah, it was just a thought.  Then it made me think of my 'sort of' solution to this question, which may or may not help sadly.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the inverse problem, to find the derivative of $x^x$ is a good example of a situation where (the sum of) two wrongs make a right. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401122/explaining-the-derivative-of-xx/426218#426218).

Comment: why this isn't shot down as a duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on my comment, it turns out that $f(x) = x^x$ has no anti-derivative expressible in terms of elementary functions.

The math involved is at a university level. If I recall correctly, it is a decidable problem to check if a given function has an anti-derivative expressible in terms of a given class of elementary functions.

The result can either be derived from something called [differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) or from [Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29), where the latter is probably the easier field to get into of the two, but is still somewhat high-level and technical (in fact, the two fields are probably related).

This is just to tell you that it is possible to show that a given function has no "nice" integral, but also to tell you that doing so is advanced.

Answer (score 10):

$x^x$ cannot be integrated since we have found no function whose derivative is $x^x$, though we can find approximations of definite integrals of $x^x$ by considering it's power series.

$$x^x=1+x\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2}x^2\ln^2(x)+\frac{1}{6}x^3\ln^3(x)+...=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n\ln^n(x)}{n!}$$

Which therefore means that

$$\int_a^b x^x dx=\int_a^b \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n\ln^n(x)}{n!}\right)dx$$

Although this certainly seems a whole lot messier, we can now approximate values of the impossible function $\displaystyle f(s)=\int_0^s x^x dx$

Comment: I think since you want to interchange limit and integration for numerical evaluation, you still need to mention some extra conditions (like uniform convergence) that justify doing it.

Comment: I almost agree with you, but rephrase "$x^x$ cannot be integrated". It is a continuous function, which can **absolutely** be integrated, in the sense that a limit of Riemann sums exists. It also does have an anti derivative, it is just not expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: It's not that we "have found no function", rather we can prove it the function given by the anti-derivative of $x^x$ cannot be expressed n terms of elementary functions.

Comment: We just *defined* the function whose derivative is $x^x$, both as an integral and as an infinite sum. True, it's not expressed with elementary functions, but what functions are in our "approved set" is quite arbitrary anyway. If $\int x^x\,dx$ were a calculator button, noone would say it can't be done (and when you think of it, $e^x$ is an elementary function, but the method to *actually* compute it isn't a lot different from what we did here with the sum).

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the antiderivative of $x^x$ is in the form of $x^xf(x)$, then we can see that $f(x)$ is the solution to the differential equation $$1=(\ln(x)+1)f(x)+f'(x)$$

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

As diligar answered, if you write $$x^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n\ln^n(x)}{n!}$$ you are then let with the problem of computing the integrals $$I_n=\int x^n\log^n(x)\,dx$$ which is doable using the gamma function. It simplifies using the exponential integral function and the result is $$I_n=-\log ^{n+1}(x)\, E_{-n}\big(-(n+1) \log (x)\big)$$ The problem is that the convergence requires quite many terms. To give you an idea, using the above expressions, I computed using numerical integration the value  $$\int_2^9 x^x\,dx \approx 1.22592630615242\times 10^8$$ Now, using the summation for $k$ terms
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k &  value \\
 10 & 2.95976367580423\times 10^6 \\
 15 & 2.90442516168767\times 10^7 \\
 20 & 8.13458442990505\times 10^7 \\
 25 & 1.13993643109235\times 10^8 \\
 30 & 1.21744554000771\times 10^8 \\
 35 & 1.22550640678100\times 10^8 \\
 40 & 1.22591514498982\times 10^8 \\
 45 & 1.22592613687818\times 10^8 \\
 50 & 1.22592630460872\times 10^8 \\
 55 & 1.22592630614356\times 10^8 \\
 60 & 1.22592630615238\times 10^8 \\
 65 & 1.22592630615241\times 10^8 \\
 70 & 1.22592630615241\times 10^8 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed easily integrate

$$\int x^a dx=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$$and

$$\int a^xdx=\frac{a^x}{\ln(a)}.$$

Check by taking the derivatives.

But

$$\int x^x dx$$ is a completely different matter, and actually you can't express it using the usual functions.

In the previous examples, the exponentiation is somewhat conserved so we would expect an antiderivative like $x^x$. But taking the derivative, a nasty factor appears.

$$\left(x^x\right)'=(1+\ln(x))x^x.$$

You can try a more general form like $f(x)^{g(x)}$, and that yields

$$\left(f(x)^{g(x)}\right)'=\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}g(x)+\ln(f(x))g'(x)\right)f(x)^{g(x)}$$ but there is little hope for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple: with differentiation and integration, the most important thing is what's the variable of integration/differentiation. Your integrand $x^x$ changes both the exponent and the base when you vary $x$, so it has nothing to do with functions of the form $a^x$ or $x^a$.

This integral isn't expressible with what we know as elementary functions (powers,log,trig,exp), but that's not surprising. Most functions are that way: only a very narrow set of functions can actually be integrated in a closed form, and even that is usually very hard (a lot of instinct, tricks and guesswork goes into computing integrals analytically - it's quite different from differentiation, which is a routine process a quick recipe can do).

Some more significant and useful integrals (and infinite sums, and solutions of transcendental equations,...) are conveniently defined as special functions, reliable algorithms are designed, tables are made, and routines in programming libraries are created. Examples are elliptic functions, gamma function, Fresnel integrals, Lambert function, Riemann zeta function,... if for whatever reason, your integral was important and frequently seen in mathematics, someone would name it. But for most expressions that aren't integrable within elementary functions, you see them once and never again. So we just integrate them numerically with one of the many reliable methods; in a sense, it's no different than what special functions from math libraries are doing, or what the calculator does when you press `sin`. It's just different in our heads, because we're so used to some functions having a special name and the rules that apply to them, we're uncomfortable when something new comes along.

Comment: This is an important point. In the real world, real life integrals are often never solvable. Elementary solutions are like gold, maybe even platinum: rare as hell and when you get 'em, they're highly prized.