# Derivative and Integral of inverse of $x^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If $x^x = a$ then define $f(a) = x$.$f$ is the inverse of $x^x$. What is then f? And what is the derivative and antiderivative of f? What is the derivation for the answer?

Comment: You can search for Lambert function

Comment: See for example [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Inverse+function+of+x%5Ex).

Comment: One rewrite it as $(\ln x)e^{\ln x}=\ln a$ ($a>0$) then use Lambert's function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is given on the [Wikipedia of the Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2), which states that

$$x^x=a\implies x=\frac{\ln a}{W(\ln a)}=e^{W(\ln a)}$$

where $W(x)$ is the Lambert W function.

---

If you wish to take the derivative of $f(x)$, use the [inverse function derivative rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation):

$$f'(x)=\frac1{g'(f(x))}$$

where $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$.  Thus,

$$g'(x)=g(x)(1+\ln x)\implies g'(f(x))=x\left(1+\ln\left(e^{W(\ln x)}\right)\right)=x(1+W(\ln x))$$

the $x$ in front is due to $f$ and $g$ being inverses.

$$f'(x)=\frac1{x(1+W(\ln x))}$$

---

To take the antiderivative, use the [antiderivative of the inverse function formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions).

$$\int f(x)\ dx=xf(x)-G(f(x))+c$$

where $G$ is the antiderivative of $g=x^x$.  Unfortunately, there is no closed form for $G$.  However, some information as to a series expansion and such is found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710894/int-xx-dx-what-is-it-and-why?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: And that's about all you can do. Nice answer.