# How would we find $ \int e ^{x(e^x+1)} dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How would we find $ \int e ^{x(e^x+1)} dx $ ?

If the integral cannot be expressed in elementary functions, then how can we prove that it cannot be expressed in elementary functions?

Comment: This might be in your interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/265780/515527 and this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155/515527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using $e^{x}=u , e^{x}dx=udx=du $ we reach to this one:
$$ \int e^{x(e^{x}+1)}dx=\int e^{xe^{x}}.e^{x}dx=\int e^{xu}.u\frac{du}{u}=\int (e^{x})^{u}du=\int u^{u}du$$

I don't continue for integration of this equation. Please refer to these pages:

[Finding $\int x^xdx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/finding-int-xxdx)

[$\int x^x\,dx$ - What is it, and why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710894/int-xx-dx-what-is-it-and-why?noredirect=1&lq=1)

https://www.quora.com/What-is-int-x-x-dx